# Call extension module from extension module using Numba AoT

Tags: python, numba, ahead-of-time-compile

I develop complex math library in `Python` using `numba`. Any functions must support `jit` and `aot`. I have functions calling functions from another file.

func1.py:

```
from numba.pycc import CC
from numba import njit

cc = CC('func1')


@njit
@cc.export('calc', 'f8(f8, f8)')
def calc(a, b):
    return a + b
```

func1.py compiles into func1.cp38-win_amd64.pyd using `cc.compile()`

func2.py:

```
import func1 as func
from numba import njit
from numba.pycc import CC

cc = CC('func2')


@njit
@cc.export('calc', 'f8(f8, f8)')
def calc(a, b):
    return func.calc(a, b)
```

If I try to compile func2.py, an error is thrown:

*numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Unknown attribute 'calc' of type Module(<module 'func1' from '...\func1.cp38-win_amd64.pyd'>)*

Can I call extension module from extension module and how to do it right?